# The following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

my **activity_main.xml** file looks like this:

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”utf-8”?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
    android:layout_height=”fill_parent”
    android:orientation=”vertical” >

    <TextView
        android:id=”@+id/mytext”
        android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
        android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
        android:text=”@string/hello” />

</LinearLayout>
```

How am I supposed to fix this error?

Comment: There is *no point* in providing a screenshot when you've just got text. It's doubly irritating when it's a link to a screenshot - which I realize is because you don't have the rep to post an inline screenshot. But *please* just put the XML into the question directly, as if it were code. Next, please give more details of the error in the question. Don't just rely on the title for context.

Comment: Well, it does not work to paste the code, because " Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code... "

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me as if you've pasted some text from Word or something similar, which means you've got "curly quotes". So your XML declaration looks like this:

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”utf-8” ?>
```

when it should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

Note the difference in quotes. You should fix *all* the quotes to be regular ASCII quotes... and ideally don't use whatever process you were following to copy and paste text from place to place... it's clearly  not friendly to XML or anything else which relies on having regular quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the version as a char literal not String literal. Exp:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
```